# how to fix: failed to connect to dumpstate service

Tags: android, adb

I try to run bugreport using adb.

```
adb bugreport
```

and i get:

```
failed to connect to dumpstate service
```

How to fix it? and get bugreport?
I try also:

```
adb shell
sh -c 'bugreport | gzip > /sdcard/bugreport.gz'
```

and same problem

Answer (score 1):

adb shell

bugreport > /sdcard/bugreport.txt